# Non inclusive cleanup policy on Nexus

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, nexus

I have to create on Nexus a cleanup policy using the **Asset Name Matcher** criteria in order to **exclude/keep a lot of artifacts** containing a specific keyword.

As described by the [Official Documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/repository-management/cleanup-policies), Nexus implements a subset of the [Elastic Search regex syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax).

The **negation syntax** should be `.*~(KEYWORD).*`. Unfortunatly the Nexus cleanup policy preview tool report me artifacts which include `KEYWORD` too in their path.

How can I solve this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You are adding `.*`, and it matches anything. So you just need `~(KEYWORD)`. Or, if it does not work, `@&~(.*foo.*)`

Comment: I am going to test your solution...

Comment: Unfortunately they don't work. The 1st one returns the keyword too, the 2nd one return sonly a single artifact without keyword. :(

Comment: Ok, but if `@&~(.*foo.*)` ("match any string but the one containing `foo`") does not work, I doubt the problem is in the regex only.

Comment: I think this an unsupported feature in Nexus the root cause.

Comment: I opened a ticket for that: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-31486 .

Answer (score 0):

The nexus ticket [NEXUS-31486](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-31486) is no longer visible because of dismission of Jira by Sonatype. I was also looking for a non inclusive `Asset Name Matcher` regular expression that will not allow packages without `-SNAPSHOT`, `-preview` or `-dev` in the name in snapshots repositories. I'm testing the following patterns:

- `@&~(.+-SNAPSHOT)`
- `@&~(.+-preview)`
- `@&~(.+-dev)`

... which should match strings without the keyword at the end of the name and they seem to work. Also:

- `@&~(.*KEYWORD.*)`: matches strings without `KEYWORD`, searching everywhere in the string
- `@&~(.+KEYWORD.*)`: matches strings without `KEYWORD`, searching everywhere in the string after a non empty prefix

... seem to work.

Answer (score -1):

you can use @ like @my-app-1.0-20000020.11111-1.jar to select only the components including that asset name.worked for me